# Accessing different mediatrays on different printers

Tags: java, printing

I'm a relatively new to Java programming and I seem to run into a wrong direction with my current project.

Currently I am working on a method for printing on different printers with multiple media trays. Till now I figured out there seems to be some different kind of AttributeSets which I could pass over to the print() method.

I managed to access either one specific printer (by name) or a media tray on the default printer. So my problem now is I would like to access SPECIFIC media trays on a SPECIFIC printer.

My code for printing on a specific media tray:

```
HashAttributeSet xset = new HashAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaTray.MAIN); // or p.e. aset.add(MediaTray.BOTTOM);  
pjob.print(aset);
```

My code for printing on a specific printer device:

```
   AttributeSet xset = new HashAttributeSet();
   xset.add(new PrinterName("UTAX-CD1222", null));
   pjob.print(xset);
```

Anyone of you knows how to combine these AttributeSets? Couldn't figure out any solutions till now. I've already tried to add one AttributeSet to the other by

```
aset.addAll((HashPrintRequestAttributeSet) xset);
```

Or to feed the print() method with 2 AttributeSets but it really seems I am getting something terribly wrong here.

I'll be glad for any help!